# What is required to achieve something like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is not about programming skills, it's about lib files and framework files. For example, I already have: jquery.js & jquery.ui.js in place, declared in the `<header>` block.

Let's say I define something in a JavaScript file, like this:

```
define("app/ui/dialogs/delete_tweet_dialog", ["module", "require", "exports", "core/component", "app/ui/with_dialog", "app/ui/dialogs/with_modal_tweet"], function(module, require, exports) {
    function deleteTweetDialog() {
        this.defaultAttrs({
            cancelSelector: ".cancel-action",
            deleteSelector: ".delete-action"
        }), this.openDeleteTweet = function(a, b) {
            this.attr.sourceEventData = b, this.displayTweet(b.tweetId, {
                modal: "delete"
            }), this.id = b.id, this.open()
        }, this.deleteTweet = function() {
            this.trigger("uiDidDeleteTweet", {
                id: this.id,
                sourceEventData: this.attr.sourceEventData
            })
        }, this.deleteTweetSuccess = function(a, b) {
            this.trigger("uiDidDeleteTweetSuccess", this.attr.sourceEventData), this.close()
        }, this.restoreFocusToTweet = function(a) {
            $(a.target).is(this.$dialog) && this.activeEl && this.trigger($(this.activeEl).closest(".tweet"), "uiShouldAddFocusStyle")
        }, this.after("initialize", function() {
            this.on("click", {
                cancelSelector: this.close,
                deleteSelector: this.deleteTweet
            }), this.on(document, "uiOpenDeleteDialog", this.openDeleteTweet), this.on(document, "dataDidDeleteTweet", this.deleteTweetSuccess), this.on(document, "uiDialogRestorePreviousFocus", this.restoreFocusToTweet), this.on(document, "uiCloseDeleteTweetDialog", this.close)
        })
    }
    var defineComponent = require("core/component"),
        withDialog = require("app/ui/with_dialog"),
        withModalTweet = require("app/ui/dialogs/with_modal_tweet"),
        DeleteTweetDialog = defineComponent(deleteTweetDialog, withDialog, withModalTweet);
    module.exports = DeleteTweetDialog
});
```

- What do I need to make the above code work?
- Does jQuery.js alone provide [module, require, exports], or is something else required to be added?
- And once I made a definition similar to this one, how can I invoke it from some other code?

I found this:

define(
    module_id /*optional*/, 
    [dependencies] /*optional*/, 
    definition function /*function for instantiating the module or object*/
);

from: http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/

However, I still don't understand how one can invoke a definition? No tutorials on Google.

Comment: You should read here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Stackoverflow is not a teaching service, it's for problem-solving in code. Posting a bunch of code without any hint as to what you're trying to achieve or what the problem is will make it very difficult for anyone to help.

Comment: The code above it easy to understand. The problem is knowing, what is required to make custom definitions as the one above work throughout the rest of your code.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use [require.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html)

Comment: The whole code example you posted looks like require.js. It is not only a file to be added but more so a code paradigm that you will have to understand first. Follow the docs.

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are trying to achieve, but it looks like it has very little or nothing to do with jquery... The name of your question also doesn't tell us anything about the problem.

Comment: define("app/ui/dialogs/delete_tweet_dialog", simply defines a "delete_tweet_dialog" with that ID on the element, and somehow, this is dynamically invoked. I am trying to figure out how I can do the same, if I create similar definitions of my own.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are showing is written as an AMD.
`RequireJS` is the library probably used here.

read more about it here: http://requirejs.org/

Comment: Yes, AMD. I am unable to find require.js in their scripts.

Comment: @Michael Johnson they might be calling it from a CDN... anyway, focus on functionality of what you need from that code. if you don't need `requirejs` then don't use it. Consider their code as callback of loaded modules (dependencies) and the function in line 2 is the one that is being executed. Also, you might need to dig a little more to get other modules as well.

Comment: Ziv Levy, thanks for your response. I am reading this article: http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/, and it is correct on a lot of things it explains. The only problem is that it doesn't show how custom defined modules are actually invoked. Do you know anything about this?

Comment: @MichaelJohnson - as far as I understand, AMD modules can be loaded only under other AMD modules or system. The root module of `requirejs` is responsible to load the first one, then its dependencies... and so on... take an hour or two to read more about it in `requirejs` site and make a simple "todo" tutorial with `requirejs`. Everything will be much clearer when you'll do the simple things first :)